# Perl Extracting XML Tag Attribute Using Split Or Regex

Tags: perl

I am working on a file upload system that also parses the files that are uploaded and generates another file based on info inside the file uploaded. The files being uploaded as XML files. I only need to parse the first XML tag in each file and only need to get the value of the single attribute in the tag.

Sample XML:

```
<LAB title="lab title goes here">...</LAB>
```

I am looking for a good way of extracting the value of the title attribute using the Perl split function or using Regex. I would use a Perl XML parser if I had the ability to install Perl modules on the server I am hosting my code on, however I do not have that ability.

This XML is located in an XML file, that I am opening and then attempting to parse out the attribute value. I have tried using both Split and Regex to no luck. However, I am not very familiar with Perl or regular expressions.

This is he basic outline my code so far:

```
open(LAB, "<", "path-to-file-goes-here") or die "Unable to open lab.\n";
foreach my $line (<LAB>) {
    my @pieces = split(/"(.*)"/, $line);
    foreach my $piece (@pieces) {
        print "$piece\n";
    }
 }
```

I have tried using split to match against title alone using

```
/title/
```

Or match against the = character or the " character using

```
/\=/ or /\"/
```

I have also tried doing similar things using regex and have had no luck as well. I am not sure if I am just not using the proper expression or if this is not possible using split/regex. Any help on the matter would be much appreciated, as I am admittedly a novice at Perl still. If this type of question has been answered elsewhere, I apologize. I did some searching and could not find a solution. Most threads suggest using an XML parsing Perl module, which I would if I had the privileges to install them.

Comment: It's 2013. Use an XML parser.

Comment: [Yes, even you can use CPAN](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828).

Answer (score 5):

"But I can't use CPAN" is a quick way to get yourself downvoted on the Perl tag (though it wasn't I who did so). There are [many ways](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828) that you can use CPAN, even if you don't have root. In fact you can have [your own Perl](http://perlbrew.pl) even if you don't have root. While I highly recommend some of those options, for now, the easiest way to do this is just to download some Pure Perl modules, and included them in your codebase. [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) has a very small, but very useful XML/DOM parser called [Mojo::DOM](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) which is a likely candidate for this kind of process.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the suggestions. I'll definitely look into Perlbrew. I admit I didn't think of ways to install modules without root access and that was pretty dumb of me.